# Yii2 advanced accessing frontend from backend using alias

Tags: yii2

I trying to access frontend/web from backend menu using alias

`yii:yii2 advanced`
`webserver : XAMPP`
`IDE:net beans`

codes I modified:

C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\common\config\aliases.php

```
Yii::setAlias('fronthome', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/frontend/web/');
```

C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\backend\views\layouts\main.php

```
if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
    $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/site/login']];
    $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'fronthome', 'url' => Yii::getAlias('@fronthome')];
```

but when accessing "fronthome" menu via backend menu; browser was returning the url:
    `http://localhost/advanced/backend/web/C:/xampp/htdocs/advanced/frontend/web`

what i wanted browser to give: 
    `http://localhost/advanced/frontend/web/`

can some one please put some light... I searched but there was no elegant solution which I could find via alias.

Thanks

I got it working by making the below change

C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\common\config\aliases.php

`Yii::setAlias('fronthome', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/frontend/web/');`

to

`Yii::setAlias('fronthome', '../../frontend/web/');`

Comment: How to link to frontend from backend is explained here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-apps-advanced.html#creating-links-from-backend-to-frontend

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-advanced-app.html#creating-links-from-backend-to-frontend

Answer (score 1):

As the links in the comments are outdated here is a snippet from the Yii2 docs:

> Creating links from backend to frontend
>   Often it's required to create links from the backend application to the frontend application. Since the frontend application may contain its own URL manager rules you need to duplicate that for the backend application by naming it differently:

```html
return [
    'components' => [
        'urlManager' => [
            // here is your normal backend url manager config
        ],
        'urlManagerFrontend' => [
            // here is your frontend URL manager config
        ],

    ],
];

 //After it is done, you can get an URL pointing to frontend like the following:

echo Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontend->createUrl(...);
```

current link to copy of relevant doc: https://yii2-framework.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/tutorial-advanced-app/

The way I have implemented this is to add a switch to my backend/config/bootstrap.php

```
    switch (YII_ENV) {
    case 'dev':
        $frontend = 'https://my-domain.lan/';
        break;
    case 'test':
        $frontend = 'https://my-domain.test/';
        break;
    case 'prod':
        $frontend = 'https://my-domain.com/';
        break;      
}
```

and then in my backend/config/main.php I added the following

```
        'urlManagerFrontend' => [
        'class' => UrlManager::className(),
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'baseUrl' => $frontend,
        'rules' => [
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        ]
    ],
```

and then where I want to use the frontend link:

```
echo Html::a('link',Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontend->createUrl('controller/view'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using params.php

Add a key on params.php on your common/config folder

```
 'frontendUrl' => 'http://frontendUrl/',
```

Then you could access it anywhere on your view by:

```
<?= Yii::$app->params['frontendUrl'] ?>
```

Hope this helps :)